# How to import/insert the npm package oauth-signature to angular 4.?

Tags: angular, xero-api

So that I could able to use/perform this functionality in angular cli.

> /*var httpMethod = 'GET',
>       url = 'http://photos.example.net/photos',
>       parameters = {
>           oauth_consumer_key : 'dpf43f3p2l4k3l03',
>           oauth_token : 'nnch734d00sl2jdk',
>           oauth_nonce : 'kllo9940pd9333jh',
>           oauth_timestamp : '1191242096',
>           oauth_signature_method : 'HMAC-SHA1',
>           oauth_version : '1.0',
>           file : 'vacation.jpg',
>           size : 'original'
>       },
>       consumerSecret = 'kd94hf93k423kf44',
>       tokenSecret = 'pfkkdhi9sl3r4s00',
>       // generates a RFC 3986 encoded, BASE64 encoded HMAC-SHA1 hash
>       encodedSignature = oauthSignature.generate(httpMethod, url, parameters, consumerSecret, tokenSecret),
>       // generates a BASE64 encode HMAC-SHA1 hash
>       signature = oauthSignature.generate(httpMethod, url, parameters, consumerSecret, tokenSecret,
>           { encodeSignature: false});*/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to install it:

```
npm install oauth-signature
```

And then import it this way?

```
import * as oauth from 'oauth-signature';
```

Comment: I already did sir but when I used the generate() function the error occurs "Cannot read property 'generate' of undefined" ,,

Comment: I tried it in my project and it is working for me. Are you doing 'oauth.generate()' ?

Comment: actually  I tried it again, it already working sir..thanks sir.